# cmake visual studio use different configuration by library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, configurationmanager

I'm trying to use differents configurations for multi-library use.

I explain : i have to use many library for one solution, but i need to change the configuration for each library target, for a debug use of my solution some library will be in 'debug' mode but some other needs a 'Render' configuration. (It's 3rdParty project i can't edit them)

I want to know if its possible.
Thanks !

Here an example the result i wanted to have :

http://i48.tinypic.com/mtugqf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost do this.  CMake allows for extra configurations by setting [`CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES), so in your case this would be

```
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES};Render" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

This needs to be after the `project` command.

However, this adds a new configuration type to *all* targets.  I don't think CMake has the ability to mix different configurations for individual targets.  You'd still have to manually modify the specific libraries' configs via the Configuration Manager once CMake had created the .sln.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, i already use the CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES but you answer the most important part of my question : '@Fraser I don't think CMake has the ability to mix different configurations for individual targets.' :) so i will try another way to update or maybe modify the sln with another language :) thanks !